# Does large amounts of javascript affect the loading time of a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

I have what I am assuming (based of my relative newness to js) a rather large amount of code within my script tags, I have more than 10 if statements that loop about 6-10 times each, amongst other simple calculations based off drop downs adding to about 150ish lines of code. The calculated variables are then sent to a redirected printable page.

Question is, is there a way to alleviate some of the weight off the page? Apart from deleting from the code, of course.

I fear the large amount of code will jumble up, say, an iPad/iPhone browser and provide wrong answers in the printable page..

Comment: you can paste you code at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yes, large amounts of javascript affect load times. No, you do not have large amounts of javascript.

Comment: It can, yes. Anything you add to a page can affect the loading time of a page.

Comment: I'm sure that if you used CSS classes it would end up in 5 lines of code ;)

Comment: @roXon there are no classes in javascript.

Comment: mattegod- Thank you, that sets my mind at ease

Comment: @jbabey really? :D I was not talking about that, but the usual mistake unexperienced programmers do - assigning bunch of over-repeated non-programatic code to elements ID instead of using CLASSES, and I was joking btw.

Comment: 150 lines of code is not a heavy load.

Comment: @roXon oh, that kind of class. sorry :P

Comment: @kazahaya the placement of the scripts within the page can affect the *perceived* load time. If the scripts are doing things that can't be seen right away, try moving them to the end of the body if you can get away with it, or use another technique for delayed loading. Get the page to render first, then load the other scripts.

Comment: @GGG I believe I have kept most of that separate, as all of the calculations are not started until a button function is pressed.

Comment: @GGG I will try to move some of the script to the bottom, at least the ones that do not affect the rest like the date/time/images etc. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider minifying your JavaScript code: http://www.minifyjavascript.com/

Comment: All it did was remove spaces between the lines of code. Does moving the code all into a continuous line actually assist in speed? I have tested that idea in other programming languages with not much success..

Comment: @kazahaya It can in larger scripts (your script is not large) or scripts that contain lots of comments. Look at jQuery for example. Minified jquery.js is much smaller than non-minified jquery.js.